# openCV doesn't play video on Fedora 28

Tags: fedora, opencv3.0

I have just started learn opencv and i encountered a problem about playing video. I use qt-creator for opencv and my os is fedora 28.

My code:

```
cv::VideoCapture vCap;
vCap.open("/home/enes/sample.mp4");
if(vCap.isOpened()){
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("Video");
    for(;;){
        if(!vCap.read(frame)) break;
        cv::imshow("Video", frame);
    }
}
```

My problem is below.

```
Failed to query video capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
libv4l2: error getting capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: device /home/enes/sample.mp4: Unable to query number of channels
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: your gstreamer installation is missing a required plugin
) in handlemessage, file /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.4.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1869
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer (CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_FILE, filename)): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(3.4.1) /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.4.1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1869: error: (-2) GStreamer: your gstreamer installation is missing a required plugin
 in function handlemessage

CvCapture_OpenNI::CvCapture_OpenNI : Failed to open input file (/home/enes/sample.mp4): Bad file extension
```

What should I do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to play MP4 video with OpenCV on Fedora 28 by building the opencv module from source, as described here: [Install OpenCV-Python in Fedora](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/dd5/tutorial_py_setup_in_fedora.html).

I also installed most of the `gstreamer-plugins-*` packages and uninstalled the managed OpenCV packages before compiling Open CV.